# extend template in extended template

Tags: twig

I'm a beginner at twig and having difficulty working out a standard method to include frames and message boxes into my pages.

Here is the code I have and how I want it to function. I've been trying different methods for the last three days and ending nowhere:

index.php

```php
echo $twig->render('mypage.twig');
```

mypage.twig

```
{%extends 'main_frame.twig'%}

{%block title}This is an example{%endblock%}

{%block body%}
  <p>This page is built with Twig</p>

  {%extends 'message_box.twig'%}
  {%block body%}
    <h1>Twig is fun</h1>
  {%endblock%}

{%block%}
```

main_frame.twig

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{%block title%}{%endblock%}</title>
  </head>
  <body>{%block body%}{%endblock%}</body>
</html>
```

message_box.twig

```
<div style='boarder: thin solid #f0f0f0;'>
  {%block body%}{%endblock%}
</div>
```

The rendered code should be something like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is an example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This page is built with Twig</p>
    <div style='boarder: thin solid #f0f0f0;'>
      <h1>Twig is fun</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the tag [`{% embed %}`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html). It's a mix between `extends` and `include` which allows you to override blocks in the embedded template, e.g.

*main.twig*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{%block title%}{%endblock%}</title>
  </head>
  <body>{%block body%}{%endblock%}</body>
</html>
```

*page.twig*

```html
{% extends "main.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    {% embed "message.twig" %}
        {% block body %}
            This is my message
        {% endblock %}
    {% endembed %}
{% endblock %}
```

*message.twig*

```html
<div class="message">
  {%block body%}{%endblock%}
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/4vmbet)

---

*`Extends` only should be used once in a template and can't even be used inside blocks*